# Why doesn't "let" work with "sh myscript" on Ubuntu, when it does with "./myscript"?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

By running the following script in `sh` and `./` mode get different result on Ubuntu

```
#!/bin/bash
x=80
z=90
let "a=$x+$z"
echo $a
```

Result:

`sh mode` gives me "blank" output, while `./ mode` yields 170.

Any explanation?

Comment: `sh` and `bash` are different shells on your system.

Comment: Even when they're **not** different shells, `bash` behaves differently (running in POSIX compatibility mode) when invoked under the name `sh`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Shell Selection via Invocation Method

`./mode` honors the shebang, which specifies that your script be invoked with `bash`. By contrast, `sh mode` explicitly uses `sh` instead, ignoring the shebang. (`. mode` doesn't run a new shell at all, but executes the commands in the script inside the same shell you're already using interactively).

---

#### Why Shell Selection Matters

`let` is a bash extension for compatibility with pre-POSIX shells.

On a platform (such as Ubuntu) where `/bin/sh` is implemented by an ash derivative, very little functionality not specified in the POSIX sh standard is available.

To perform arithmetic in a manner compatible with all POSIX-compliant shells (from the initial 1992 publication of the POSIX sh standard), use the following syntax:

```
a=$(( x + z ))
```